# How to add to the "New from Template" list?

Tags: aptana

I have added a new file template to Aptana Studio 3.0.4 as described in this documentation section:
http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+template

The new template now shows up when I select **File->New->File** and enter an appropriate filename. So far so good.

Now I'd like my new template to show up in the **File->New From Template** listing. I have not been able to locate any documentation that explains how to do this.

Comment: Would you mind taking a moment and marking my response as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok this is actually fairly simple. For my example I will be creating an alternative php file template with a html5 structure.

1. On the main menu **click**: *Command*->*PHP*->*Edit this bundle*.  You should see a folder named "PHP" appear in your *Project Explorer* window.
2. **Open** the project by double clicking on it and **open** the folder *templates*. Inside I see two files: template.php and template.rb
3. **Create** the file type you want to add here and name it *phpHTML5.php*.
4. **Open** the newly created file and **paste** (or create) your template inside and **save**.
5. In the same folder **open** template.rb
6. Printed at the bottom of the file is the structure:

   ```
   template "PHP Template" do |t|
    t.filetype = "*.php"
    t.location = "templates/template.php"
   end
   ```

**Copy** and **paste** it below changing the *template* to *phpHTML5* the following changes:

```
    template "PHP Template" do |t|
     t.filetype = "*.php"
     t.location = "templates/phpHTML5.php"
    end
```

7. **Save** and **Restart** Aptana.

NOTE: You may 'delete' the project PHP but be **careful to deselect** the "Delete project contents on disk(cannot be undone)" otherwise you will be in trouble...

Any problems with this just let me know, and I will see if I can help with the rest.

Comment: Too bad we have to restart Aptana, this is painful. Anyway, thanks, that should be marked as the answer.