# Dreamweaver to Aptana migrate - what to do with templates

Tags: html, aptana, dreamweaver

I have been using Dreamweaver for simple html web development and have been using `.dwt` templates for my html pages. There are both static and dynamic pages. I have migrated to Aptana for my IDE, but not sure what to do with `dwt` templates. How can I migrate them to Aptana, do they have a similar feature as I am willing to rewrite them in Aptana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a page here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+template that shows how to add to the available templates and a question here: [How to add to the "New from Template" list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391812/how-to-add-to-the-new-from-template-list) that shows how to add them to the File > New from template menu.